# SeekBar Custom Style in Android

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a SeekBar with custom style. Here is the xml files. custom_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<size android:height="8dp"
    android:width="8dp"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffff"
    />
```

And custom_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ababab" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

It works fine on any Android Emulator and looks like this
[SeekBarOnEmulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu3cJ.png)

But on devices it changes and looks like this [SeekBarOnDevice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nErem.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, custom_thumb.xml also contains parent tag Shape with android:shape="oval" attribute and custom_progress.xml contains parent layer-list tag. it wasn't copied